# Why does npm start not work for React JS?

Tags: javascript, create-react-app

I cant seem to make my React app run on localhost. Could anyone help me solve why the `npm start` is not working? I have followed all the instructions but nothing seems to work given to me by the command line and have kept retrying to the process multiple times but still no luck.

```
 $ npm start

 > appify@0.1.0 start C:\Users\javie\Desktop\appify\appify
 > react-scripts start


 There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
 It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

 The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

 "babel-eslint": "10.0.3"

 Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
 However, a different version of babel-eslint was detected higher up in the tree:

 C:\Users\javie\node_modules\babel-eslint (version: 7.1.1)

 Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

 If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
 That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

 To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

 1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
 2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
 3. Remove "babel-eslint" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
 4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

 In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
 If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

 5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
    This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

 6. Check if C:\Users\javie\node_modules\babel-eslint is outside your project directory.
   For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

 7. Try running npm ls babel-eslint in your project folder.
    This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed babel eslint.

 If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
 That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

 P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno 1
 npm ERR! appify@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
 npm ERR! Exit status 1
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Failed at the appify@0.1.0 start script.
 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR!     C:\Users\javie\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-18T20_13_42_803Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you try uninstalling `babel-eslint` from the other `node_modules` directory (`C:\Users\javie\node_modules\babel-eslint`)?

Comment: no what would be the command to remove it

Comment: Might depend on how you installed it, looks like a global install, in which case you can do `npm uninstall -g babel-eslint`. Otherwise navigating to that directory (`C:\Users\javie\node_modules`) and running `npm uninstall babel-eslint`. Uninstalling this might mess with other projects that rely on this installation, but it's better not to globally install most packages.

Comment: I've gotten this error before, and usually its because I had globally installed packages.  After I deleted them from my global npm package directory, things seemed to start working again.